# Calling a view function with AJAX not working when current path has sub directory or url parameter (Django)

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-urls

I am using AJAX to call a view function when my pages load to return a count value (no. of items in basket). This works fine for most of my url paths but when the current path has a sub directory or url parameter value I get a 404 error.

Below are a some of my url patterns. The bottom one is the view function I call to return the count value. When I visit the 'orders' path the basket count is returned successfully but for the 'order_history' and 'view_order' paths I get the 404, e.g. 'Not Found: /view_order/basket_count'

```
path("my_orders", views.orders, name="orders"),
path("my_orders/history", views.order_history, name="order_history"),
path("view_order/<int:id>", views.view_order, name="view_order"),
path("basket_count", views.basket_count, name="basket_count"),
```

Very new to Python/Django so I'm sure I'm not grasping something very fundamental here and the url patterns are not resolving correctly. I previously had the basket_count in another file called utils.py and referenced it with utils.basket_count which gives the same outcome. I suppose I could just call the function within each of my views but my intention here was to experiment with AJAX. Is there a simple change to my url patterns that will fix this issue with my current setup or is it simply bad practice?

My AJAX code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var basket_count = new XMLHttpRequest();
  basket_count.open('GET', '/basket_count/', true);
  basket_count.send();

  basket_count.onload = function() {

    var count = JSON.parse(basket_count.responseText);
    if (count.count > 0) {
        document.getElementById('nav_basket_count').innerHTML = ' [' + count.count + ']';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('nav_basket_count').innerHTML = '';
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Post your Ajax bro. I'm assuming the problem is there.

Comment: You haven't really given enough information here (where is your Ajax code?) but I suspect the issue is not to do with Python or Django at all, but just with URL paths; you always want to request a path starting with a slash, eg `/basket_count` not just `basket_count`.

Comment: @Jay thanks, you were right! Just solved it and will update my post. Incorrect use of forward slashes on my AJAX function call!

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, you were spot on!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my AJAX code. I had a trailing forward slash in the url when there should just have been one at the start, as shown below.

```
basket_count.open('GET', '/basket_count', true);
```